# How do I make a script that lauches Tiwoli Work Scheduler by entering username and password itself?

Tags: unix, ksh

I'm trying to write a script that goes to the path abc/hik/tws/TWCDWP85/TWS/bin/      
 **(Tiwoli Work Scheduler's launch file path)**
and launches **conman**(launch file) by running ./conman command.
On running ./conman , 
I get three prompts as following

1) Specify your user name account:
2) Enter your password:
3) Confirm your password: 
 For all the three prompts, I want my script to enter same string or just press enter.
 


This is the message I get when I run my script.[image]

Please help .

Answer (score 0):

With `yes` you can give some string repeatedly.

```
yes twcdwp85 | job_status.ksh
```

Or try

```
printf "%s\n" "user" "pw123" "pw123" | job_status.sh
```

Someone can see the `pw123` using `ps`. You can better fill the password in a variable and use

```
printf "%s\n" "user" "${donthackme}" "${donthackme}" | job_status.sh
```

Comment: I ran my script with yes twcdwp85, still getting same message.Additional message "/bin/ksh: twcdwp85:  not found".

Comment: I don't know. Perhaps try giving the path `abc/hik/tws/TWCDWP85/TWS/bin.job_status.sh`, or try printf first. TWS took some effort against hacking, perhaps flushing passwords as my solution is blocked by `conman`.